# ACK responses from Firebase CCS not reaching Smack Library's Stanza Listener

Tags: android, smack, firebase-cloud-messaging

I still haven't found the answer as to why I am not getting an ACK response from Firebase CCS when I create a message Stanza using Smack Library in my Android app. I was able to get the ACK response before, but the code I had in place was lost due to my machine crashing.

My connection is working fine since I get the message I send to myself on my FirebaseMessageService Class on my onMessageReceive method.

Here is  how I initial my Stanza Listener using the Smack API:

```
filter = new StanzaFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Stanza stanza) {
            // Accept messages from GCM CCS.
            if (stanza.hasExtension(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE)) {
                return true;
            }
            // Reject messages that are not from GCM CCS.
            return false;
        }
    };

    stanza_listen = new StanzaListener() {
        @Override
        public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {

            String string = ""+packet.getExtension(GCM_NAMESPACE);
            String rayString = packet.getExtension(GCM_NAMESPACE).toXML().toString();


            Log.d("extension","here you go; "+string+" xmlpacket:\n\n"+rayString+" other extension:\n\n"+packet.getExtension(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME,GCM_NAMESPACE));

            JSONObject jason = null;
            try {
                jason = new JSONObject(string);
                Log.d("myJson","here is JSon: "+jason);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("couldnt","couldnt get extension: "+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

When I try to Log.d on my logs the call packet.getExtension(GCM_NAMESPACE) I get something that looks like this ***org.smack.DefaultExtensionElement@4215b*** Also the logs show an empty extension like this one:

```
<gcm xmlns:google:mobile:data>
There's no JSON payload. Its empty 
</gcm>
```

I call **other_connection.addAsyncStanzaListener(stanza_listen,filter)** to begin
listening for incoming messages from Firebase CCS.

Any advice would be appreciated.

thanks